# Unused default export when first setting up with `vue init webpack my-project`

Tags: vuejs2

I am using `vue init webpack my-project` to start learning vue.js I am version 2.9.2 and when I start the project it only renders the logo, nothing else. I even downloaded the vue plug-in on Chrome and they're no issue shown.

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <h2>Essential Links</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://vuejs.org" target="_blank">Core Docs</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://forum.vuejs.org" target="_blank">Forum</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://chat.vuejs.org" target="_blank">Community Chat</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/vuejs" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
      <br />
      <li><a href="http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/" target="_blank">Docs for This Template</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Ecosystem</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://router.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vuex.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[image: Project structure]

I am very new to vue and wanted test it out and I really like Angular's CLI but this one has me completely confused.

Comment: Try to restart and your app if you can see the hello world at least. This is most likely browser related also check your console for errors

Comment: What's in your index.html and app.vue? It's likely you are not using the Hello.vue component anywhere, that's why you are getting the unused export error, and it's not showing.